# Filter two irregular lists by the repeated elements in one of them

Tags: python, list, filter

I've been fiddling with seemingly simple issue for a while now and I cant find an easy answer. Consider these two lists of lists:

```
a1 = [
    [[0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34]],
    [[0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34],
     [0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34]]
]

a2 = [
    [[2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35]],
    [[2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 3, 5, 13, 21, 35],
     [2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35]]
]
```

their shapes are `(N, M, P*)`, where the `P*` indicates that the number of elements `P` is not the same across all sublists (but it is the same for sublists in `a2` with the same indexes as sublists in `a1`). Sometimes these two lists will be *complete*, and all the sublists will contain the same elements, ie (in this example): `0.3, 1.75, 2.1, 3.3, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34` for all sublists in `a1`, and `2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35` for all sublists in `a1`. In this case, the shape is `(N, M, P)`.

I need a way to filter **both lists simultaneously** according to the elements that can be found in *all*  sublists of `a1`. In the above example the elements `1.75` and `3.3` are missing in some of the `a1` sublists, so the results would be:

```
a1_f = [0.3, 2.1, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34]
a2_f = [2, 5, 13, 21, 35]
```

where `3` and `8` where removed from `a2` since they are linked to the non-repeated elements `1.75` and `3.3` that were removed from `a1`.

My actual lists will be much larger and of arbitrary shape, so I'm after a general approach. Elements in both lists will always be ordered from min to max, but I'm not sure it makes any difference.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `zip` to make tuples.  Use `set.intersection` to find the elements in all lists ... or use the `all` function on the series.

Comment: I tried using `set.intersect` but I keep getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` which I'm guessing has something to do with how I'm using `zip`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

a1_f = set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(a1)))
a2_f = set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(a2)))

# {11.34, 0.3, 4.66, 2.1, 8.9}
# {2, 35, 5, 13, 21}
```

And if you want them in sorted list:

```
a1_f = sorted(set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(a1))))
a2_f = sorted(set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(a2))))

# [0.3, 2.1, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34]
# [2, 5, 13, 21, 35]
```

Edit: if what you are looking for is pairing `a1` and `a2` up before the job, assuming the data structure is guaranteed to be 1 to 1, you can do this:

```
result = sorted(set.intersection(*map(lambda x: set(zip(*x)), zip(*(chain.from_iterable(l) for l in (a1, a2))))))
# [(0.3, 2), (2.1, 5), (4.66, 13), (8.9, 21), (11.34, 35)]

a1_f, a2_f = [list(map(lambda x: x[i], result)) for i in range(2)]

a1_f
# [0.3, 2.1, 4.66, 8.9, 11.34]

a2_f
# [2, 5, 13, 21, 35]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it handles both lists independently. The `a2` list should be filtered according to `a1`, not by itself.

Comment: Based on my understanding of your clarification, I've updated the answer.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Note that this solution would not follow the original item order. It works only because the sample data in the question happens to be pre-sorted so you can restore the order using `sorted`.

Comment: @blhsing agreed. That's why I asked if the data structure is guaranteed.  If order is important though I'd just loop through.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following does what you want, without constructing unnecessary copies of the arrays:

```
from functools import reduce
rows = ((set(r1), set(r2)) for c1, c2 in zip(a1, a2) for r1, r2 in zip(c1, c2))
a1_f, a2_f = reduce(lambda a_f, row: (a_f[0] & row[0], a_f[1] & row[1]), rows)
```

It gathers all the lists into a generator, two at a time, converting them into sets. It then calculates the intersections to find the smallest sets. If you need the results as lists, you can convert them back with `list(a1_f)` etc.

That said, it's not obvious what you're gaining by filtering both the lists simultaneously. Doing each one separately would make the code simpler and not slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.reduce` Along with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `set.intersection`

```
data = map(set, chain.from_iterable(a1))
a1_f  = reduce(set.intersection, data, next(data)))
```

Comment: But this is not extended to also affect `a2`.